# Subclass UIView with Swift, use in Nib

Tags: xcode, swift, uiview, nib, initwithcoder

I am trying to subclass UIView with Swift and give my class an init with one parameter. The required **Init With Coder** initializer is tripping me up. I do, in fact, want to be able to plop my view into a Nib file. My understanding is that this will call **Init With Coder**. Is there any way to have this initializer called with addl. params, other than the decoder? Right now I am assigning default values to my instance variables, as shown below, so that the code will compile.

```
class ClassName: UIView {

    var dimension: Int = {
        return 5
    }()

}
```

My initializers are set up as shown below.

```
init(Int: dimension) {
    self.dimension = dimension
    super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

**Is it true that if you initialize a view via a Nib file, there is no way to pass in any novel parameters?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views created from a Nib will always be initialized using `init(coder:)`.
For that reason you **must** either initialize all your variables immediately with proper values or make them optional.

```
var dimension = 0
```